# Jquery toggle effects not working

Tags: jquery, onclick, toggle

I have a div of icons that I want to drop down when clicking on an img above. I've set the jquery toggle effect on the `#mainicons` div and it's not working, there's a sort of glitch. And it might be because it's the container and not each icon particularly (the `<a>` or `<i>` elements). But that is actually the effect I want the whole div just dropping down and not each icon individually. So is there a way to do it or is just not possible?

```js
// Show hide on click

    function showNavi(){
        $("#navigationin").toggle('slow','swing');
      $('#chevron').toggleClass('rotate180');
      $('.rainbow').toggleClass('changecolor');
    };
// Scroll to top
 //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
   $('.scrolltotop').fadeIn();
  } else {
   $('.scrolltotop').fadeOut();
  }
 });
 
 //Click event to scroll to top
 $('.scrolltotop').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
  return false;
 });

// Random color
function entryOver(classnm) {
    $(classnm).css('border-color',randomColor({
   luminosity: 'bright',
   format: 'hsl' 
}))
};
function notEntryOver(classnm) {
    $(classnm).css('border-color',"#dadada")
};

// Icons drop down
function iconsFunction() {
  $('#mainicons').toggle("blind");
  $('#avatar i').toggleClass('rotateavatar');
};

  $( function() {
    $( ".about" ).draggable({cursor: "move"});
  } );
```

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none
}
/*-- PAGINATION --*/

.pagination {
  margin-top:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
   
.pagination a {
margin-bottom:10px;
color:#fff;
background-color:#bababa;
display: inline-block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 100%;
line-height: 20px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
   
.pagination a:hover {
color:#58acfa;
background:#fff;
}

.current_page{
color:#58acfa;
border:1px solid #58acfa;
margin-bottom:10px;
display: inline-block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 100%;
line-height: 20px;
    margin-left:5px;
}

    /*----- MAIN CONTAINER -----*/

#container {
position: relative;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}


  /*------ MENU -----*/
  .about{
    cursor:move;
    z-index:1000;
    position:fixed;
    width:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #bababa;
    background:white;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease;
    -o-transition: .5s ease;
    transition: .5s ease;
  }


  /* Main icons */

  #mainicons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    left: 23px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
    -o-transition: all .7s ease;
    transition: all .7s ease;
  }

#mainicons>a {
margin-top: 10px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

  #mainicons i {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #bababa;
    border-radius:100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
  }

  #mainicons i:hover {
      background:#fff;
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  
  #mainicons .fa-home:hover{
      color:red;
  }
  #mainicons .fa-comment:hover{
      color:#fe9a2e;
  }
  #mainicons .fa-download:hover{
      color:#37ce00;
  }
  #mainicons .fa-address-card:hover{
      color:#58acfa;
  }

  /* Avatar */

  #avatar {
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:100%;
    border:3px solid #dadada;
    margin:10px 0 0 13px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    z-index:10;
  }

  #avatar img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
  }
  
  #avatar i{
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      font-size:17px;
      line-height:55px;
      text-align:center;
      color:#bababa;
      opacity:0;
      background:#fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
  }
  
  #avatar:hover i{
      opacity:1;
  }
  
  .rotateavatar{
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);      
  }
  /* Description */

  #description {
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:10px 0 10px 90px;
    color: #000;
    background: #dadada;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    width:180px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }

  .rainbow {
      position:absolute;
      width:200%;
      height:2px;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      opacity:0.5;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
  background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
     -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;  
}

.rainbow.changecolor{
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
  
  /* Search box */

  #search {
    margin:10px auto 10px auto;
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #404040;
    background: #fff;
    border:1px solid black;
  }
  
  #search .fa-search{
      font-size:12px!important;
      float:right;
      margin-right:5px;
      line-height:25px;
  }

  /* Navigation */

#description .fa-chevron-down{
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:12px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
#description .fa-chevron-down:hover{
    color:#58acfa;
}
.rotate180{
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);  
}

#navigationin i {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #404040!important;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin:5px 6px 5px 6px;
    padding:3px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
  }
  #navigationin i:hover {
-webkit-transform : rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform : rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform : rotate(360deg);
-o-transform : rotate(360deg);
transform : rotate(360deg);
  }
   #navigationin .fa-question-circle:hover{
      color:red!important;
  }
  #navigationin .fa-link:hover{
      color:#fe9a2e!important;
  }
  #navigationin .fa-music:hover{
      color:#ffde07!important;
  }
  #navigationin .fa-user-circle-o:hover{
      color:#37ce00!important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/randomcolor/0.5.2/randomColor.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


<div id="container">
  
<div class="about" onmouseover="entryOver(this)" onmouseout="notEntryOver(this)">


<div id="avatar" onclick="iconsFunction(this)"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/5c231601a0942f139489cca966931eef/4cxodkk/AOSorhvq1/tumblr_static_dpxyh4zatkgsocg4888kg8wg8.png"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></div>

<div id="description">
<span class="rainbow"></span>
<p>Welcome to <font color="#58acfa">actorsblog</font>!</p>
<p>Here you will find all sorts of fandom <b>pictures</b>, <b>icons</b> and <b>edits</b>!</p>
<p>If you have a question, a  request or a post to submit, <b>click the avatar</b>!</p>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" id="chevron" onclick="showNavi()"></i>
      <div id="navigationin" hidden>
    <center>
    <a href="{text:Link One Url}" title="{text:Link One Title}"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>
    <a href="{text:Link Two Url}" title="{text:Link Two Title}"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
    <a href="{text:Link Three Url}" title="{text:Link Three Title}"><i class="fa fa-music"></i></a>
    <a href="{text:Link Four Url}" title="{text:Link Four Title}"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i></a>
    </center>
    </div>
    <!--End navigationin-->
    <div id="search">
    <form action="/search" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="SEARCH" style="position:absolute; width:120px;     line-height:25px; padding-left:10px; font-family:{select:Body font}; font-size: 12px;      background:transparent; border:1px solid transparent; color:"#404040";"/>
    <i class="fa fa-search" type="submit"></i>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
  
  <div id="mainicons" hidden>
<a href="/" title="home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
<a href="/ask" title="contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></a>
<a href="/submit" title="sumbit"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
<a href="/about" title="about"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i></a>
</div>
<!--End mainicons-->

<div class="pagination">
<a href="{PreviousPage}">←</a>

<span class="current_page">1</span>

<a class="jump_page" href="{URL}">2</a>

<a href="{NextPage}">→</a>

</div>
<!--End pager-->

</div><!--End about--> 
</div>
```

Thank you for answering! also if you want [here's](https://codepen.io/wydmae/pen/LyKBYr) the codepen.

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle of your code, if possible ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6jq04606/1/ @MayankPandeyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using jQuery `.slideToggle('slow');` as opposed to `.toggle('slow','swing');`. It will do basically the same thing, but it will slide down instead of left to right. jQuery `.toggle();` is *supposed* to go from left to right

```js
// Show hide on click

function showNavi() {
  $("#navigationin").slideToggle('slow');
  $('#chevron').toggleClass('rotate180');
  $('.rainbow').toggleClass('changecolor');
};
// Scroll to top
//Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.scrolltotop').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.scrolltotop').fadeOut();
  }
});

//Click event to scroll to top
$('.scrolltotop').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 800);
  return false;
});

// Random color
function entryOver(classnm) {
  $(classnm).css('border-color', randomColor({
    luminosity: 'bright',
    format: 'hsl'
  }))
};

function notEntryOver(classnm) {
  $(classnm).css('border-color', "#dadada")
};

// Icons drop down
function iconsFunction() {
  $('#mainicons').slideToggle('slow');
  $('#avatar i').toggleClass('rotateavatar');
};

$(function() {
  $(".about").draggable({
    cursor: "move"
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none
}


/*-- PAGINATION --*/

.pagination {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pagination a {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #bababa;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.pagination a:hover {
  color: #58acfa;
  background: #fff;
}

.current_page {
  color: #58acfa;
  border: 1px solid #58acfa;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}


/*----- MAIN CONTAINER -----*/

#container {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}


/*------ MENU -----*/

.about {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #bababa;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease;
  -o-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}


/* Main icons */

#mainicons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 23px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: transform .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: transform .7s ease;
  -o-transition: transform .7s ease;
  transition: transform .7s ease;
}

#mainicons i {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #bababa;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

#mainicons i:hover {
  background: #fff;
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

#mainicons .fa-home:hover {
  color: red;
}

#mainicons .fa-comment:hover {
  color: #fe9a2e;
}

#mainicons .fa-download:hover {
  color: #37ce00;
}

#mainicons .fa-address-card:hover {
  color: #58acfa;
}


/* Avatar */

#avatar {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #dadada;
  margin: 10px 0 0 13px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

#avatar i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bababa;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

#avatar:hover i {
  opacity: 1;
}

.rotateavatar {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}


/* Description */

#description {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 90px;
  color: #000;
  background: #dadada;
  padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
  width: 180px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.rainbow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 2px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2), color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22));
  background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2), color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22));
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.rainbow.changecolor {
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
  /* Safari */
  transform: translate(-50%);
}


/* Search box */

#search {
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #404040;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#search .fa-search {
  font-size: 12px!important;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
  line-height: 25px;
}


/* Navigation */

#description .fa-chevron-down {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

#description .fa-chevron-down:hover {
  color: #58acfa;
}

.rotate180 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#navigationin i {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #404040!important;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px 6px 5px 6px;
  padding: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

#navigationin i:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

#navigationin .fa-question-circle:hover {
  color: red!important;
}

#navigationin .fa-link:hover {
  color: #fe9a2e!important;
}

#navigationin .fa-music:hover {
  color: #ffde07!important;
}

#navigationin .fa-user-circle-o:hover {
  color: #37ce00!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/randomcolor/0.5.2/randomColor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


<div id="container">

  <div class="about" onmouseover="entryOver(this)" onmouseout="notEntryOver(this)">


    <div id="avatar" onclick="iconsFunction(this)"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/5c231601a0942f139489cca966931eef/4cxodkk/AOSorhvq1/tumblr_static_dpxyh4zatkgsocg4888kg8wg8.png"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></div>

    <div id="description">
      <span class="rainbow"></span>
      <p>Welcome to
        <font color="#58acfa">actorsblog</font>!</p>
      <p>Here you will find all sorts of fandom <b>pictures</b>, <b>icons</b> and <b>edits</b>!</p>
      <p>If you have a question, a request or a post to submit, <b>click the avatar</b>!</p>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" id="chevron" onclick="showNavi()"></i>
      <div id="navigationin" hidden>
        <center>
          <a href="{text:Link One Url}" title="{text:Link One Title}"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>
          <a href="{text:Link Two Url}" title="{text:Link Two Title}"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
          <a href="{text:Link Three Url}" title="{text:Link Three Title}"><i class="fa fa-music"></i></a>
          <a href="{text:Link Four Url}" title="{text:Link Four Title}"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i></a>
        </center>
      </div>
      <!--End navigationin-->
      <div id="search">
        <form action="/search" method="get">
          <input type="text" name="q" value="SEARCH" style="position:absolute; width:120px;     line-height:25px; padding-left:10px; font-family:{select:Body font}; font-size: 12px;      background:transparent; border:1px solid transparent; color:" #404040 ";"/>
          <i class="fa fa-search" type="submit"></i>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="mainicons" hidden>
      <a href="/" title="home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
      <a href="/ask" title="contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></a>
      <a href="/submit" title="sumbit"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
      <a href="/about" title="about"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i></a>
    </div>
    <!--End mainicons-->

    <div class="pagination">
      <a href="{PreviousPage}">←</a>

      <span class="current_page">1</span>

      <a class="jump_page" href="{URL}">2</a>

      <a href="{NextPage}">→</a>

    </div>
    <!--End pager-->

  </div>
  <!--End about-->
</div>
```

P.S. when you click the avatar there are four options. One of them has a typo... It's 'submit' not 'sumbit'

**Edit:**

The problem is still occurring, so you also need to change `transition: all .7s ease` to `transition: transform .7s ease`. When the icon is hovered over, it is given the CSS transform rotate etc. You only need to apply the .7s to the transform, not to all (which includes slideToggle)

Comment: Thank you for the typo and also the slideToggle I guess it is better but it's still doing the same thing as if it's going to fast so we can't see it?

Comment: @MaëlleJumel Not entirely sure what the problem is... Could you explain?

Comment: Do you see for example how the navigation (arrow in the description) shows up slowly? You can actually see the animation but you can't for the mainicons

Comment: Yes I noticed that but I applied on #mainicons aniway and you can actually understand what I mean if you put the duration of the effect to like 15000ms or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147527/discussion-between-maelle-jumel-and-james-douglas).